# Template a Cover letter using macros?

Tags: macros, acronyms

I'd like to create a cover letter where I can insert the company name, and various other consistent pieces of information as a macro to be expanded when the document is compiled. I'm very new to LaTeX, but I'm certain this can be done with a macro; how can I do this?

I'd like it to be this sort of thing:

```
\define{compname}{European XFEL}{European X-Ray Free Electron Laser}
```

So that when some command reading `compname` is compiled it spits out the long or short form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of ways of doing this. The `glossaries` package is pretty good for defining acronyms (things with long and short versions), but it might be overkill for this.

You could just do

```
\documentclass{letter}
\newcommand{\shortname}{}
\newcommand{\longname}{}
\newcommand{\compname}[2]{\renewcommand{\shortname}{#1}\renewcommand{\longname}{#2}}

\compname{European XFEL}{European X-Ray Free Electron Laser}
\begin{document}
The short version of the name is: \shortname

The long version of the name is: \longname
\end{document}
```

Comment: I did not realise how simple that would be. Fantastic.